# AWS VPC for EKS node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a Node group in my EKS cluster, but I am getting '''NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster'''.
[image: EKS node group health error]

After reading many documentations I think the problem is in the VPC configuration. I've tried multiple solutions like enabling DNS host name, and adding endpoints to the subnets but still having the same error.
Can any one guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the VPC and Subnet configurations are correct and that the EC2 instances that you are trying to create the Node Group with have the correct security group settings.

Next, ensure that the EC2 instances have the correct IAM role attached and that it has the necessary permissions for the EKS cluster.

Finally, ensure that the IAM user or role that you are using to create the Node Group has the correct permission for the EKS cluster.

If all of the above are configured correctly, you may need to check the EKS cluster logs to troubleshoot further. You can do this by running the command "kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp" in the EKS cluster.